# c++ - Conversion from Custom Classes to built in types

Tags: c++, casting

For the sake of clarity Let my new class be:

```
class MyInt{
    public: 
      MyInt(int x){theInt = x /10;} 
      int operator+(int x){return 10 * theInt + x;} 
    private 
      int theInt; 
};
```

let's say I want to be able to define:

```
MyInt Three(30); 
int thirty = Three;
```

But in order to get this result I'm writing:

```
MyInt Three(30); 
int thirty = Three + 0;
```

how can I get automatic conversion from my Custom class to a built-in type?

Comment: Remark: it's usually a _bad idea_ to have _both_ conversions _implicit_ (here `int`->`MyInt` via the non-explicit constructor _and_ `MyInt`->`int` via a conversion operator). (Consider for example `std::string`, for which there is an implicit conversion _from_ `const char*` (converting constructor) but not _to_ `const char*` (for this you need to call `.c_str()` or related member functions).) [Also, typo: `private` -> `private:`]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

With a type conversion function:

```
class MyInt{
    public: 
      MyInt(int x){theInt = x /10;} 
      int operator+(int x){return 10 * theInt + x;} 

      operator int() const { return theInt; } // <--

    private 
      int theInt; 
};
```

Comment: With the added note that doing this should be transparent.  That is, if you are converting to an `int`, the class should be a numeric class and not some custom class that does something totally unrelated.

Comment: It should be `const` (but `operator+` too, if not a non-member function), and should probably return `10 * theInt` according to OP's weirdness.

Comment: @gx_ thanks, I agree about const. I'll let OP do the arithmetic :)

Comment: how about more complex types, like `std::vector<int>` or `std::vector<std::tuple<int, long>>`? how do i determine what `operator` i should write? can you give some examples?

Comment: @qkhhly You can't write conversion operators *from* standard library classes (vector, etc) if that's what you mean. From a custom class written by you *to* a vector? Well, nothing special about them. The name of the type conversion function is the target type, so for example `operator std::vector<int>() { /* code here */ }`